# About the Android Studio Logcat function

Tags: android-studio

I'm using the Logcat function in Android Studio,
I'd like to ask you that an uncomfortable phenomenon that did not occur in my memory in the past is currently occurring now.

in the first place
If you are looking at the Logcat tab and you run the application again
There is a very uncomfortable problem that automatically changes to the Run tab.

secondly
When you re-run the application
In the past, the logcat was automatically erased
These days, it's very uncomfortable because it's still there.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the configuration dropdown menu, click `Edit Configurations...`

[image: Configuration dropdown menu]

Then in the `Miscellaneous` tab, check `Show logcat automatically` and `Clear log before launch`.

[image: Miscellaneous tab]